# Append values to a specific element in a string with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have an element in local storage with multiple elements, for simplicity, I will make the element:

```
<div id="outer">
  <ul id="inner">
    <li id="item">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The element is saved as a string and I want to manipulate the contents.
Like such:

```
let local_storage_element = localStorage.getItem("val")  
$(local_storage_element+':last-child').append("<p>something</p>")
```

No matter what selector I add after local_storage_element it will always append the value to the string not to the selected element(:last-child in this case)

does anyone know how to append to a specific element within the string??

Comment: it will not recognise last child becasue that is still string ..

Comment: I also tried let local_storage_element = $(localStorage.getItem("val")) and it didnt make a difference, if that is what you mean.

Comment: What did you store in localStorage? aka what is the value of `local_storage_element`?

Comment: The above string <div id="outer"> ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you have written jquery in the title there is a `javascript` tag added also so I thought why not provide an answer that justifies your needs and helps you accomplish the task in the same way you want.

> The
>   [**`DocumentFragment`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) interface represents a minimal document object that has no parent. It
>   is used as a lightweight version of Document that stores a segment of
>   a document structure comprised of nodes just like a standard document.
>   The key difference is that because the document fragment isn't part of
>   the active document tree structure, changes made to the fragment don't
>   affect the document, cause reflow, or incur any performance impact
>   that can occur when changes are made.

So how to do it as the DocumentFragment still appends node with it and not string, we will create a temp element and add the HTML from the `localStorage` using `innerHtml` and then append the `firstChild` of that temp node i.e our actual string which is now treated as a node, to the document fragment and then search and appends HTML to it, we will use our temp element to add HTML every time see below.

I will append a new child `div` to the element `#outer` in the string given above in the post here is the working  [**`FIDDLE`**](https://jsfiddle.net/buttflattery/nvnss2ac/9/) as SO does not support localStorage you can see it working there open the console to view the resulting HTML with the new child added and below is the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if (localStorage.getItem('html') === null) {
        localStorage.setItem('html', '<div id="outer"><ul id="inner"><li id="item"></i></ul></div>');
    }

    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('html');

    frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
    temp.innerHTML = '<div class="new-child"></div>'
    frag.querySelector("#outer").appendChild(temp.firstChild);

    console.log(frag.querySelector("#outer"));

    localStorage.removeItem('html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use string as selector. If you want transform string to html then you should put it in some element as innerHTML. So try create some hidden div and insert your string as HTML to it. Something like this

```
var your_string = '<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li></ul>';
document.querySelector('.hidden').innerHTML = your_string;
document.querySelector('ul li:last-child').innerHTML = 'your content';
document.querySelector('.result').appendChild(document.querySelector('ul'));
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/eq3v7oh7/)

Comment: I'm aware of doing it this way, although this is an assignment and I have to do it using local storage.

Comment: if you want to use HTML selectors you should make your string HTML. In localstorage you can save strings, not HTML. So you should parse string to HTML. Also you can use strings operations

Comment: you can use `DocumentFragment` to play with the string. but you have to create a temp node/element first in order to append the string to the document fragment

Answer (score 0):

The problem may arise when you get `'<div id="outer">'` from localStorage to use it as a selector since it only accepts `"#outer"` to be a selector. If you want to add an element to be the last child of parent's element, you could use `after()` instead of `append()`.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  
  if ($("#charl").children().length === 0)
  {
    // if using after with no element inside ul then it will be inserted after il
    $("#charl").html("<li>foo</li>")
  }
  else {
    $("#charl li").after("<li>bar</li>")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="charl">
  <li>Foo</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Bill it's a string that I get from localstorage not a HTML element